# Como se faz um formulário inline com bootstrap sem usar tabelas

Tags: html5, twitter-bootstrap

Não sou designer, mas necessito de um formulário `inline` sem usar tabela e `responsivo` como o da imagem.

Estou a 2 dias tentando e nada, a `<label>nome campo</label>` sempre estraga o posicionamento dos campos.

Estou tentando fazer algo como na imagem em anexo.[image: IMAGEM EXEMPLO]

Comment: Olá, coloque o código do que você já tentou até agora. Caso queira, a documentação do bootstrap tem um exemplo de form inline para você: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Segue o código que tentei [link] http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/T2EgQDgbx1

Comment: Fabio, da uma olhada nesse exemplo. https://jsfiddle.net/3teg3yL2/  Não seria algo assim que você gostaria? O que acontece no seu de errado exatamente?

Answer (score 1):

Existe um exemplo de como fazer isso na [documentação do bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>
```

Comment: É interessante, mas o elemento label fica encima do campo de texto e eu não consigo coloca-lo em uma linha tipo: label campo --> label campo

Comment: Tem algum css no seu form além do bootstrap?

Comment: Erlon Charles somente o Bootstrap e mais nenhum css meu problema está sendo a Label exemplo no link. O texto fica acima do campo de texto e eu preciso ao lado esquerdo do campo. [link] http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/T2EgQDgbx1

Comment: No link que você mandou você está usando a classe `form-horizontal` ao invés de usar `form-inlinel`. troca que funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Com a biblioteca do bootstrap pode fazer assim:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ficou abaixo um do outro.[link] http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/sSRMRGD0sf

Comment: Já actualizei o exemplo para a versão que está a utilizar.

Comment: Isso solucionou em parte, agora possuo problema com o elemento label antes do elemento input. Necessito de um cadastro linear. Ex: Nome: campo de texto + espaço + E-mail: campo de texto.  A label sempre fica acima do campo de texto, eu necessito ao lado [link] http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/T2EgQDgbx1

Answer (score 0):

Form simples para envio de mensagem em contato

```
 <form method="post"">
                                    <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="6u"><input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" /></div>
                                        <div class="6u"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>                                    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row 50%">
                                    <div class="12u"><input type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row 50%">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <textarea name="mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="12u">
                                            <h2 id="aguarde"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" >Aguarde...</h2>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Enviar/>                                    
                                        </div>                                  
                                    </div>                                                              
                                </form>
```

Aprendi, sobre bootstrap com um exemplo de sites super legais com HTML5 CSS3 e Bootstrap. CORRIGINDO: http://html5up.net/ baixa um site de exemplo e faz a festa.

Comment: Este também  não deu certo :(

Comment: http://html5up.net/ Esse é o site ! exemplos ótimos para estudo.

Comment: Segui o exemplo deste link agora não consigo colocar o texto ao lado esquerdo do campo [link]http://www.codeply.com/go/bp/T2EgQDgbx1